# Update login form and message on terminal

Tags: arch-linux, login

In linux its possible to customize the login page with the lightdm package. But it will force the use of Xorg.

Is there a way to customize the login form and message before the user login on the tty interface.

[image]

Comment: The default message comes from `/etc/issue` I think: you may be able to specify a custom file on the `agetty` command line - exactly where will depend on what invokes `agetty` on your OS (maybe the `getty@ttyN.service` files, if Arch uses `systemd`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @steeldriver commented, the text before the login prompt is stored in the file `/etc/issue` and it's printed right after the `agetty` be called.

`/usr/bin/agetty` is responsable for creating tty on startup.

We can look at the systemd tree with

```
systemctl status
```

In Arch, the specific files for systemd agetty are stored at `/etc/systemd/getty.target.wants/getty1.service`.